# Does inline css override a stylesheet css file?

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to style 4 divs (next to each other) of the same class with a `margin-right` of `35px` to divide them evenly, except for the last div so it doesn't add extra margins to the `30px` `margin` already assigned to the right side of the wrapper.

Now, I'm not an expert at coding yet so I might be wrong here, but I was thinking that I could add `margin-right: 0;` inline to the last div to override the property value `35px` in my stylesheet.

Would this work? Or is there a different solution that I'm not seeing?

**Edit: thanks to you all, the last-child pseudo selector worked! :-)**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. And post a complete code example please.

Comment: In my opinion inline styling is a bad practice. You could add an additional class like `last-div` with `margin-right: 0 !important;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would override the style and work. But another solution would be to use the `:last-child` pseudo selector in the sheet.

For more on `last-child`:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Comment: this is the correct answer to your question.  upvoting.

Comment: Providing a brief code example would round up your answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need to add inline CSS, you can do that easily using the `:last-child` psuedo selector. For example, if this is your HTML:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

And the following CSS has been applied to it:

```
.box {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 35px;
}
```

You can remove the `margin-right` from the last div using this CSS:

```
.box:last-child {
     margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 317px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
.box:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: (a) IDs must be unique and (b) the OP wants to style based on a class, not an ID.

Answer (score 1):

An inline style sheet (added with the `<style>` element) is treated no differently for the purposes of the cascade than an external stylesheet (added with the `<link>` element).

A rule added using the `style` attribute is treated as having higher specificity then any stylesheet, but can still be overridden by `!important` rules (unless it it is also `!important`).

For further reading, see [The Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade).

Rather than using an inline style, you may be better off using [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo) or [`:last-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-of-type-pseudo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `:last-child` selector to eliminate the margin from the last div:

```css
.ctr {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.foo {
  margin-right: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.foo:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="ctr">
  <div class="foo">one</div>
  <div class="foo">two</div>
  <div class="foo">three</div>
  <div class="foo">four</div>
</div>
```